# Building an table using procedures

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to create an procedure that returns an table with some information of my database, it lists the number of the HOTEL by how many clients used each type of their credit cards on the hotel

Keeping in mind that there is more than 50 hotels and 3 types of credit cards, i want the procedure to run through the data and list then in the table

```
DELIMITER //    
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testing` //
CREATE PROCEDURE `testing`(OUT param1 VARCHAR(40))

BEGIN

DECLARE id_cnpjEstabelecimento VARCHAR(40);
DECLARE id_redeCartão VARCHAR(255);

SELECT (cnpjEstabelecimento) 
FROM fpcsmovatlantica201308tst04;
SET id_cnpjEstabelecimento := cnpjEstabelecimento;

SELECT (id_redeCartão) 
FROM fpcsmovatlantica201308tst04;
SET id_redeCartão := id_redeCartão;

SELECT count(*)
FROM fpcsmovatlantica201308tst04;
WHERE redeCartão like 'id_redeCartão%';
AND cnpjEstabelecimento like 'id_cnpjEstabelecimento%';

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

An example of an select

```
 SELECT count(*)
 FROM fpcsmovatlantica201308tst04
 WHERE redeCartão like 'Cielo%'
 AND cnpjEstabelecimento like '02223966000466%'
```

the cnpjEstabelecimento got several values, more than 100+, so it's inviable to make all the selects

I don't even have to use procedures to make it, the final result was

```
SELECT cnpjEstabelecimento, redeCartão, count(*)
FROM fpcsmovatlantica201308tst04
WHERE redeCartão like 'Cielo%'
GROUP BY cnpjEstabelecimento,redeCartão like 'Cielo%'
ORDER BY cnpjEstabelecimento ASC;
```

Comment: There is another problem, i need to make a procedure to make these selects automatic, so they run through the database and do this thing just by calling the procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have one table, which looks kind of like this:

```
|hotelId|cardType|etc...
```

I'd go with:

```
Select hotelId, cardType, count(*)
from myTable
group by hotelId, cardType
```

I tested it [here](http://w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_orderby) with the following SQL:

```
SELECT country, city, count(*)
from customers
group by country, city
ORDER BY Country;
```

Comment: Yes, it is like this, but the problem is there are several hotelIDs, so if i have to do this way i have to create more than 100+ Selects

Comment: @GabrielTaniguchi I updated my example. It should give you what I think you want.

Comment: Another problem is that there is some different types of credict cards, but all of them got the same initial names, for example:

Cielo - Maestro
Cielo - Mastercard

I need to make a 'like' statement to gather them